# Routing(?) in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, routes

I need my webite to display info in a certain language, based on a query in my webite's URL (e.g. www.website.com/index.php?country=FR). How can I do that with vanilla JS and not React/Angular?

My approach:

1) JS recognizes a query in the URL (in this case- 'country=FR') and then appends a js file, which has neccessary french words in it defined by variables.
2) JS in my script tag that's in the HTML file, appends the main page markup text with template literals in it.
3)

I don't know, whether the browser fails to either fetch the language file itself or its variables. At the moment it does not render anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const template= `
        <h1>Good Morning: ${goodmorning} </h1>
        <h2>Good Evening: ${goodevening} </h2>
        <h3>My name is: ${mynameis}</h3>`


        function markupAppend() {
        $('body').html(template);
        console.log('Markup loaded')
        }

        markupAppend()

    </script>

</body>
</html>

=========================
Main.js

var domain = window.location.href;
var FRString = domain.includes("country=FR");
var ESString = domain.includes("country=ES");

if (FRString) {
  $('head').append(`<script src="./Language_files/FRENCHwords.js" />`)
}

if (ESString) {
  $('head').append(`<script src="./Language_files/SPANISHwords.js" />`)
}

=========================
FRENCHwords.js

const goodmorning = 'Bonjour';
const goodevening = 'Bonsoir';
const mynameis = 'Mon nom est';

=========================
SPANISHwords.js

const goodmorning = 'Buenos dias';
const goodevening = 'Buenas tardes';
const mynameis = 'Mi nombre es';

No errors displayed, the page is just not rendering...
```

Comment: The way that's usually done is using a translation library. Most of them are called some variation of "i18n" (stands for **i**nternationalisatio**n** - there are 18 letters shortened). You would only use transation keys within your page and the translation library will substitute them with the appropriate translations. Generally, the library will go with the browser language first, but can be overriden by a different thing (e.g., having **lang=fr** in the URL). There doesn't need to be any routing involved

Answer (score 0):

In Your main.js file, you are using domain.includes, it only returns the domain name but not the entire URL. You can use window.location.href.includes for this.

Instead of:  domain.includes("country=FR");
Try: window.location.href.includes("country=FR");